# element.bind("resize.container", function() { .. } );

Tags: jquery, events, resize, bind

What does this do:

```
element.bind("resize.container", function() { 
     //.....
});
```

Apparently, it gets called with the resize event, but what is the .container bit for?

I also didn't find any documentation about this kind of syntax "event.bla" -- what is the purpose?

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: jQuery doc explains the [dot syntax in event context](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.container` is used as a namespace. Using this namespace you can unbind the `resize` event on element as below

```
element.unbind("resize.container");//This will unbind only the handlers which are bound using "resize.container".

element.unbind("resize");//this will unbind all the resize event handlers on this element.
```

Note: event namespacing is widely used in plugin development so as not to alter with the events bound on the element by the page or other plugins

Jquery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

Answer (score 0):

resize.container is the event that is getting bound with the function to the element.  It seems like a custom event someone created, called like `$().trigger("resize.container");`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the jQuery documentation for [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind) you see the signature for `bind()` is:

```
.bind( eventType, [eventData,] handler(eventObject) )
```

So in this case `resize.container` is an eventType. That's all it is. It's not a native event (like, say, `click` or `change` or `load`), it's a custom event. The `.` part is about namespaces. You can read about [namespaced events here](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events).